# Admin Panel Save button is unresponsive in Manage Products menu and other places

Tags: php, magento

We just migrated our application from our development environment to the UAT server that runs on the cloud. After deploying all the files and setting up the magento pages everything seemed to work fine. The only issues seem to be in the magento admin panel, Catalog -> Manage Products menu when i am trying to add product and save it is unresponsive. nothing happens. Infact the save option is not responding in alomost all of the magento admin panel pages. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should probably be a javascript issue. You should try replacing the prototype.js file with the one that you have used in the test environment.